# How to run ndk-build with relative path in gradle task

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, executable, ndk-build

I want to run `ndkbuild` task of my app gradle. The file to execute is in `\\ndk-bundle\\build\\ndk-build` relatively to the gradle file.

Here is my current task of my `build.gradle` (app):

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    executable = "${projectDir}\\ndk-bundle\\build\\ndk-build"
    args = [ 'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk']
}
```

As you see I tried to use the variable `${projectDir}` so that ohter member of my team will execute without having to change this path. But I got this error :

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\path\to\my\project\app\ndk-bundle\build\ndk-build" (in directory "D:\path\to\my\project\app"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a Win32 valid application`

But if I run the command `D:\path\to\my\project\app\ndk-bundle\build\ndk-build` in a terminal, it's working... So the path is valid but it can't be executed.

Comment: Does the path contain a file with the _exact_ name `ndk-build` (and not e.g. `ndk-build.cmd`)?

Comment: The path contain both `ndk-build` and `ndk-build.cmd`. And both are runnable form command line.

Comment: Well, a Windows expert would have to explain exactly what's happening. But here's my guess: The `ndk-build` that you have is actually a Linux binary. But since the Windows terminal supports omitting file extensions for executables, running `ndk-build.cmd` is a valid outcome of you saying `ndk-build`, so that's what it ends up doing. Gradle on the other hand will only run the executable with the exact name you provided (i.e. `ndk-build` cannot mean `ndk-build.cmd` or `ndk-build.exe` or anything else), so it ends up trying to run a binary intended for a different OS.

Comment: I suggest you use the `.cmd` extension in your Gradle executable task.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I got that error : `ndk-build.cmd finished with non-zero exit value 2`. It's less verbose than my previous error.